# "code ." command is not working in command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

After creating angular application using angular cli, I tried to open the solution in visual studio code using "code ." command from command prompt, but it shows below error. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Have you read this tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you are using Windows, make sure your `vscode` bin folder is declared on your Environment Variable `Path`. Either user or system will do but, I recommend declaring on System Variables therefore it's available for all users.

Visual studio code usually is installed on the following directories depending on your installation architecture. Declare one of those on your `Path` and it should be available already.

x86

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

x64

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

> **Warning:** Older versions of Windows requires you to restart the operating system in order to change environment variables effectively.