# How to open a file from terminal in a tmux session in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmux

One can open a file from the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code via:

```
 code -r something.dat
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for me when I work in the terminal within a tmux-session. The error I get is:

```
-bash: code: command not found
```

I googled the error and it seems I have to include vscode on my `Path` variable (example: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176780/code-command-is-not-working-in-command-prompt)). 
I'm now confused on what to do as it works from the normal integrated terminal but doesn't work in the tmux "environment".
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you first started the tmux server from a terminal without this in PATH and you are not adding it in any of the shell startup files that the shell uses when started from tmux (remember tmux starts login shells by default).